# Button does not respond to DOM cssStyleDeclaration

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am sure this is a simple bug but I´ve been over an hour trying to find where the problem is and definetely could use a different point of view.

In the following function I change the style of two buttons. One of them, responds correctly and indeed its font size changes when the function gets called (`deleteBtnToDecorate`).

---

The other one, I cant understand why it doesn´t responds and it´s font size doesn´t get changed (`doneBtnToDecorate`):

```js
 changeStyle: function(idNumber){
        const liToDecorate = document.getElementById(`id${idNumber}`)
        const doneBtnToDecorate = document.getElementById(`idDone${idNumber}`)
        const deleteBtnToDecorate = document.getElementById(`idDelete${idNumber}`)
      
        liToDecorate.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
        doneBtnToDecorate.style.fontSize = '0.8rem'
        deleteBtnToDecorate.style.fontSize = '1.1rem'
      }
```

Things I´ve tried:

- console logged clicking in both buttons to verify all of them are
  targeted correctly. **They are**
- changed css font size manually to verify in case bootstrap might be
  the problem (although if it would be, the other button wouldn´t
  change either) but anyway...the fact is: **It changes succesfully
  when i do it via CSS** and not the DOM

This is my full code:

```js
 <ul class="item-list-ul">
        <li 
          v-for="(i, index) in items" 
          :id="`id${index}`" 
          :key="index">{{ i }}
          <div class="item-butons">
            <b-button :id="`idDone${index}`" class="done-btn" @click="changeStyle(index)" size="sm" variant="outline-dark">Hecho!</b-button>
            <b-button :id="`idDelete${index}`" class="delete-btn" @click="deleteItem(i)" size="sm"  variant="warning">Borrar</b-button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TodoList',
    methods: {
      changeStyle: function(idNumber){
        const liToDecorate = document.getElementById(`id${idNumber}`)
        const doneBtnToDecorate = document.getElementById(`idDone${idNumber}`)
        const deleteBtnToDecorate = document.getElementById(`idDelete${idNumber}`)
      
        liToDecorate.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
        doneBtnToDecorate.style.fontSize = '0.8rem'
        deleteBtnToDecorate.style.fontSize = '1.1rem'
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="css">
.item-wrapper{
    padding: 4vh 3vh 4vh 3vh;
}
.item-list-ul{
  margin-right: 4vh;
}
.item-list-ul li{
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
} 
.item-list-ul li{
  font-size: 1.4em !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.done-btn{
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.delete-btn{
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS uses `!important`:

```
.done-btn {
  ...
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  ...
}
```

If you use `!important` it will take precedence over inline styles.

Incidentally, this is not really the correct way to do this in Vue. You should apply the changes within the template via either `class` or `style` bindings rather than grabbing elements and changing them directly.

Comment: Thanks I dont know how i missed that. I see I knew DOM couldnt be very clean solution but I since the class depends on the changeStyle function being clicked, I didnt know clear how should i do it.

Comment: @J.Cake The key is getting your data structures correct. Don't rely on the DOM to hold state, make sure everything you need lives in JavaScript data structures that are accessible to your component. Then the template just needs to generate suitable markup based on those data structures. `changeStyle` should update some suitable, reactive data and then the template will automatically re-run to reflect the new data.